# Axios error 431 because of param too high

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, http-status-code-403

I'm making an App with React front and Node back. The front makes calls to the back with Axios. Everything works fine except for an API call that has, for some users, a big array as argument. Here is my code :

1 - React front that makes the call.

```
Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/tickets/timing", {
          //I pass an array with multiple ids
          params: {
            tickets: AllIds
          }
        })
          .then(response => { 
          //do some stuff
        })
```

2 - Node back that will route the call to the good function

```
const express = require('express');
const {MyFunction} = require('../controllers/TicketsControllers');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/timing', MyFunction);
```

3 - Then the function process the call and send back the result

```
const MyFunction = (req, res) => {
 //Do stuffs
}
```

The problem is that I got an error on my front site `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/tickets/timing?...' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

The thing is it works fine when the array , that is pass as a parameter, doesn't contain too much values. So it seems that my request is too big.

How could I solve this ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT

It seems that Axios is not the problem. The issue is just happening in Chrome. It works fine on Safari and Firefox. Even on Chrome private navigation browser it works fine.

Comment: You've talked about three different problems. 403 error is `Forbidden`, typically issued because the user lacks permissions. `413 Request Entity Too Large` is the error code you should get when the request is too large. You'll need to use the `cors` package in your backend to allow requests from `http://localhost:3001/`

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake on the title. The error is 431. I already use CORS on my backend and everything works fine except for that call when the param is very big. When the array's length is 190 it doesn't work, but when it's 10 it works fine. So the problem seems to come from the size of the param